# How to call shell script in java code in eclipse?

Tags: java, shell

I am unable to call a shell script from my java code.
Here is my code. Can anyone let me know what I am missing here.

```
protected boolean shellExecute() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/baibhav/try_scripts/javacall.sh");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please tell us exactly what is not working. Is there any `Exception`?

Comment: Paste in stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sh before the script name

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/baibhav/try_scripts/javacall.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting IO execption, please check your scripts path

Answer (score 0):

If the script has output, you need to get the returned `Process`' output and read from it the process does not block.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/baibhav/try_scripts/javacall.sh");
InputStream scriptStdout = p.getInputStream();
// Read from input stream and proecess it.

// In finally block:
scriptStdout.close();
```

You didn't say whether you had an exception thrown or whether the system just hanged.  If it hanged, that's probably the reason.

Also, consider using `ProcessBuilder` instead.